# Help finding app history

Tags: lg

i know there is a place i can go on my lg motion and see the history of all the apps ever downloaded to my phone, including the ones that have been removed. This same place will show the last date the app was installed but I can't remember where that is.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the Play Store and click `My Apps` and then `All`

Comment: What's is interesting is to find out how many times I have tried to give an app a chance. I install, test it, uninstall, come back months later, do it again. I seem to have installed Amazon Kindle at least 3 times, that I can see.